# Pop up not working (not opening) for a java applet

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on an asp.net application. I have a third party java applet to open with the url.
The following code gets rendered:

```
<a id="pqr" class="link" onclick="javascript:cancelEventPropagation(event);return true;" href="http://abc:8888/forms/frmservlet?config=abc&amp;userid=lmn@IAAD01DB&amp;otherparams=arguments=global.cust_no=1245411%20global.autostart_form=F21490%20global.policy_no=12452514%20+TERM=E:\\lmn\\abc\\forms\\abc.res" target="_blank">Hop</a>
```

The issue is that, when we are working in xp and with old browser, this code snippet is working.
While working in Windows 8, the link does not works.
When we paste the same link in a new tab in Win 8, its working fine.

Please help
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that canceleventpropagation is not valid, or if it is, it's canceling the current event before it is processed to open the link. I'd try removing that part.

Comment: It is working fine with a windows xp machine. No problem with the code chunk.

Comment: Do you have a cancelEventPropagation function? Earlier, I was assuming that perhaps there was something in old IEs that is no longer there, but it looks like there's never been a function by that name in the normal browsers.  Any errors thrown on the console?